# Request.getParameter("param") is null

Tags: servlet, java

```
<form action="Service" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="param" id="param"/>
        <input type="file" name="f" id="f"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Пытаюсь отправить файл и поле на java сервлет.
Оба параметра нормально отправляются (видно через fiddler), но request.getParameter("param") возвращает null.
Если вручную считать поток пришедших данных

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
```

То там всё есть.
Как считать все post параметры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша форма не отправляет POST-параметры. Обратите внимание на `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Вы шлете данные формы как составное содержимое. Для разбора данных можете воспользоваться [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/).

Comment: Спасибо, через список
ServletFileUpload uploader = new ServletFileUpload(fileFactory);
List<FileItem> fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(c);

читается норм. И кто такой дибильный API придумал...